# Почему не распознает русский текст в XML?

Tags: xml, powershell, utf-8

Вот код на PowerShell (5.1):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
 
 
$fileIn1 = "Bridges.gpx" 
 
$XPath = "//gpx:wpt"
 
$ns = @{gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"}
 
[hashtable]$wptsUnique = @{}
 
 
 
 
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $fileIn1 -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
$nsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsManager.AddNamespace("gpx", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1")
$wpts = $xml.selectNodes($XPath, $nsManager)
 
 
foreach($wpt in $wpts)
{
write-host $wpt.name
}
```

Вот XML файл Bridges.gpx:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="OsmAnd+ 3.9.5"
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:osmand="https://osmand.net"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
xmlns:wptx1="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1"
xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
xmlns:trp="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TripExtensions/v1"
xmlns:adv="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/AdventuresExtensions/v1"
xmlns:prs="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/PressureExtension/v1"
xmlns:tmd="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TripMetaDataExtensions/v1"
xmlns:vptm="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ViaPointTransportationModeExtensions/v1"
xmlns:ctx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/CreationTimeExtension/v1"
xmlns:gpxacc="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/AccelerationExtension/v1"
xmlns:gpxpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/PowerExtension/v1"
xmlns:vidx1="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/VideoExtension/v1">
<metadata>
<name>favourites</name>
</metadata>
 
<wpt lat="55.555555" lon="37.777777">
<name> Сарай на даче</name>
<desc>7</desc>
<type>Dacha</type>
<extensions>
<osmand:background>circle</osmand:background>
</extensions>
</wpt>
```

Почему при запуске скрипта я вместо "Сарай на даче" получаю "Ð‘Ñ‹Ð²ÑˆÐ°Ñ ÑÐµÐ»ÑŒÑ" ? Кодировка XML файла точно UTF-8. И что мне сделать со скриптом, чтобы он начал правильно печатать текст ?

Comment: начать скрипт с `chcp 65001`

Comment: Скрипт был уже записан с UTF8 BOM

Comment: BOM и CHCP - не имеют ничего общего

Comment: Пофигу, стало выводить вот такое:  


Active code page: 65001  
Ð‘Ñ‹Ð²ÑˆÐ°Ñ ÑÐµÐ»ÑŒÑ

Comment: Ага, вместо "Сарай на даче" получаешь "Бывшая мельница", причём в нерусской win-1252  )))

Comment: А все-таки, как мне заставить мой скрипт печатать текст в читабельном виде, а не кракозябрами?